# Issue with session_start(), ob_start() and security

Tags: php, security

In my web admin area I have using very simple logic:

```
session_start(); ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
contents...
ob_end_flush();
```

Yes this is working perfect, redirect to login page. But the comic point is that I can see the content of index.php (that protected!!!) [here](http://web-sniffer.net/) 
What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put an [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) and [`exit`](http://php.net/exit) after the [`header`](http://php.net/header) call to prevent any further execution/output:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    ob_end_clean();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Abra kadabra

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    die("GET LOST YO");
}
```

Comment: Better without the message, but killing the script fixed the problem easily.

Comment: *Shrug*, browsers shouldnt see this anyway, since you're getting redirected. And if somebody's sneaky then... well, you just told him to get lost, as he always should have :P

Comment: Even though it doesn't matter in this case it's still not a good idea to use `die()` anywhere in a website.

Comment: The same as what? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You should make all script content in IF.

```
session_start(); 
ob_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    contents...
}
else {
    header("Location: login.php");
ob_end_flush();
```